# my sql statement for update doesnt work

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am not able to execute an update statement. There seems to be some issue with my update statement.

What I'm doing now is that I'm trying to update the duplicated email address and replace (update) with non-duplicated email. Therefore, in order to update, my SQL statement will check my database against the input and if `((firstname  && lastname && dateofbirth) || (phoneNo && address)` match what the user input, it will update the database; that is: update the duplicated email address with non-duplicated email, then remove all the duplicated email after the update has been executed.

However, I'm not able to figure out what's wrong. Here is my update statement:

```
 try {
         System.out.println("it came here where filepart!=null");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);
            // connects to the database
            conn = getConnection();

            // constructs SQL statement
          stmt = conn.createStatement();

           //sqll should be update


          String sql1 ="UPDATE registration SET emailAddress = ? where ((firstName = ? && lastName= ? && dateOfBirth= ?) || (phoneNo= ? && address= ?))" ;

            //Using a PreparedStatement to save the file
            PreparedStatement statement1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            System.out.println(firstName+"firstname");
            statement1.setString(1, firstName);
            statement1.setString(2, lastName);
          statement1.setString(3, dateOfBirth); 
            statement1.setString(4, phoneNo);
          statement1.setString(5, address);
       statement1.executeUpdate();
       statement1.close();
     String sql2="delete registration from registration inner join (select min(userId) as lastId, emailAddress from registration where emailAddress in ( select emailAddress  from registration group by emailAddress having count(*) > 1) group by emailAddress) duplic on duplic.emailAddress = registration.emailAddress where registration.userId > duplic.lastId";

   stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);



            //sends the statement to the database server

           // if (row > 0) {

             // getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").include(request, response);
              //  message = "You have successfully registered.";
            //}


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //  message = "You have failed to registered. Please try again.";
         //   ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    // ex.printStackTrace();
                    //silent
                    //message="You have failed to log in";
                     getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/FailedMsg.jsp").include(request, response);
                }
            }      
          rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }}
 }
```

Comment: exactly HOW is this not working? "some issue" doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @marB the update doesn't seem to be executing. i dont see any update in my sql database and instead, the delete sql statement is executed.

Comment: Did you debug your servlet to see exactly what the UPDATE statement looks like.  Then copy and paste it to mysql and see if it executes?

Comment: @RickS i did not debug because im not sure how the debug works at rational application development. However,  i did try the sql statement at mysql database. It works prefectly fine. I am able to achieve what i wanted at mysql database.

Comment: How do you know what the UPDATE statement that you're building in code looks like if you don't debug it or log it somewhere?

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions. You need to either handle them, or rethrow, or at absolute minimum log them.

Comment: Use of `&&` is invalid in SQL, you need to use `AND`, a `||` in standard SQL is the string concatenation operator, you need to use `OR` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your sql string first:

```
    String sql1 ="UPDATE registration SET emailAddress = ? where ((firstName = ? && lastName= ? && dateOfBirth= ?) || (phoneNo= ? && address= ?))" ;
```

In the above string you have 6 question marks (placeholders). But you are setting only the five of them and indeed in the wrong way. What you are doing is set firstname for `emailAddress`, lastname for `firstName` and so on. The first placeholder(?) is for `emailAddress` so you have to do as follows:

```
    statement1.setString(1, emailAddress);
    statement1.setString(2, firstName);
    statement1.setString(3, lastName); 
    statement1.setString(4, dateOfBirth);
    statement1.setString(5, phoneNo);
    statement1.setString(6, address);
```

Can this be a reason you cannot update correctly? You might also be getting some exception. You should look to the RAD console.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be at where clause. Try to apply `Trim()` , `ToUpper()`, or `ToLower()` function to string data columns and input value. Try to match `firstname`, `lastname`, and `dateofbirth` first. If it works, try with matching phone and address data. Don't forget to clean up/normalize data before you match.